# Jekyll cannot see the value of baseurl in _config.yml

Tags: git, jekyll, revert

Weirdest thing every as the title says it. I have spent hours bumping my head on the keyboard trying to understand why the changes in my baseurl key in my _config.yml never work.

E. even if I have baseurl: "2020/labs/oshanghai/students/benoit-mrejen"

It will still not appear and remain empty.

I have even tried to display it on an html page, and it still appears empty

The website is hosted there: http://fabacademy.org/2020/labs/oshanghai/students/benoit-mrejen/_pages/02-Project-management.html

And the repo is here: https://gitlab.fabcloud.org/academany/fabacademy/2020/labs/oshanghai/students/benoit-mrejen

The weirdest of them all is that it used to work last night. I made a few changes, broke it, did a git revert and now it's still broken... I'm about to give up on Jekyll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the base url in your repository is currently "", so maybe you have changed it meanwhile. Otherwise it should not show up anywhere.

That said, this link might help you:
https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/

Parker is one of the Jekyll maintainers. I don't know if the base url is the same you were looking for.

Finally, still not sure how you are using the base url, have you done something like this?

```
{{ page.path | prepend:site.baseurl }}
```

Or generally speaking, you can access base url with site. as a prefix.

```
{{site.baseurl}}
```

Does this help you?

Kind regards,
Christian